# How can I stop my output from always equaling 0?

Tags: roblox

I wrote this script that should output the values of I, II, and III but each value always outputs as 0.

```
I=script.Parent.Parent.I.Value
II=script.Parent.Parent.II.Value
III=script.Parent.Parent.III.Value

script.Parent.Changed:Connect(function()
    if script.Parent.Value == true then
        script.Parent.Value = false
        script.Parent.Parent.Turn.Value = 1
        print("cast")
        print(I+II+III) 
    end
end)
```

script.parent is a bool value

I've tried printing each variable individually, but they always come out as 0
'`print(I)`.'
When checking in the explorer they definitely equal the correct value(not 0).
The values are numerical, I made sure of that, and I simply cannot think of any other reason this would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, Sorry for wasting yall's time!
Variables were not asked after they were changed, so they still read what they were prior.